# NSFetchedResultContoller can do that?

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Need some advice into: *Can NSFetchedResultController do this?*

```
UITableView:
  [section name] <= {entity: Section, value: title}
    [cell title] <= {entity: Cell, value: title}

Model:
  [entity: Section, properties: title] <->> [entity: Cell, properties: title, imgPath]
```

Trouble:
  *Count of sections, and their titles is working, can't fetch object from relationship to Cell*

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible. In fact I think that you can use the "standard" table view data source methods and fetched results controller delegate methods if you create the FRC with the `sectionNameKeyPath` set to "section.title":

```
// Fetch "Cell" entities:
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Cell"];

// First sort descriptor for grouping the cells into sections, sorted by section title:
NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"section.title" ascending:YES];
// Second sort descriptor for sorting the cells within each section:
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort1, sort2, nil];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                        initWithFetchRequest:request
                                        managedObjectContext:context
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"section.title"
                                                   cacheName:nil];
```

(I have assumed that you have an inverse relationship `section` from the *Cell* entity to the *Section* entity.)

Comment: Work like a charm :)

self.fetchController.sections.count; // return count of section

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = self.fetchController.sections[section];
[secInfo numberOfObjects]; // return count of row in section

Comment: id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> secInfo = self.fetchController.sections[section];
NSString *title = [secInfo name]; // return title for header

Comment: MYMOObject *cellObj = [self.fetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // return cell object